# JS Country Redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I can't run this code, how can I run it?

Where exactly am I making mistakes? Why does not work?

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      // If the visitor is browsing from Turkey.
      if (location.country_code === 'TR') {
        // Redirect him to the .
        window.location.href = 'new url';
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and added the missing }) at the end. It still gives console errors because you for some reason nest your ajax

Comment: You also do not console.log the result, and you mix http and https. Lastly you will likely get a CORS error - the code redirects to a shutdown function so the server likely does not even work

Comment: Could you please write the working version of this code

Comment: Start here: https://ipstack.com/product - the server you use is no longer in use or moved to https://freegeoip.app/json/ which does not respond

Comment: the http://ip-api.com/json it works here. But I can't.

Comment: `{"status":"fail","message":"SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/"}` so we cannot use it in stacksnippets.

Comment: I need help with blogspot url redirect. Visitors to the site will go www.google.co in Turkey. US visitors will stop at blogspot.com. https://turkmenleryapim.blogspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax iswrong, try removing the extra jQuery.ajax({}) and semi-colon like this:

```js
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      // If the visitor is browsing from Turkey.
      if (location.country_code === 'TR') {
        // Redirect him to the .
        window.location.href = 'new url';
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Already mentioned and the semicolon is just fine. There are many more problems with the code